# Webview not loading javascript or CSS

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

Hey all this is my first Android app here.

I am loading in my LAN website i am serving off an IIS server in my house. (192.x.x.x). The page loads up just fine if i use my computer and goto http://192.x.x.x/index.html

However, when i place that same path in my webview i do see the web page but it doesnt seem to be loading up the javascript nor the css?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqueryv1.9.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jMobile.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link href='css/jqueryMobile.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

My webview code is this:

```
package com.example.mainactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://192.xxx.x.xx/index.html");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        this.setContentView(mWebView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

What could i be missing to cause this to happen?

**update**

[image]

**update 2**

[image]

**update 3**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did the css style is load and effective?

Comment: Not sure without the javascript loading first (its jquery mobile)

Comment: and then, you should ensure your IIS server received the js file or css file request.

Comment: I stand corrected. I thought it already did the **import android.webkit.WebSettings;**.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable javascript in the WebView to load javascript

```
mWebView = new WebView(this);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: you have done a typo. It should be `webSettings` and not `WebSettings`.

Comment: omg!! that correction was for line 3 and not line 2. Just copy paste my code. that will do.