# Android WebView: only loads HTML, does not load JS or CSS (in some devices)

Tags: java, javascript, android, eclipse, webview

I have an web app called Vane ([link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expedyte.iweather)). It works properly on my phone (Samsung S3) and some devices, but in some devices it just loads the html part no js no css..

Any reason why? This is my first app and i don't know much of java.. 
Pictures:

This is how it should work (Samsung s3)

[image]

And this is how it looks in some other devices, only html (Xtouch phone)

[image]

Webview code:

```
package com.expedyte.vane;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebStorage;


public class IWeather extends Activity {


    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
        view.loadUrl(url);
       return true;
   }
}


public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
            GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

WebView mWebView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iweather);
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);        
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath(); 
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(databasePath);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    // Below required for geolocation
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient()
    { 
        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) { 
                quotaUpdater.updateQuota(5 * 1024 * 1024); 
            } 
        }); 

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/weather/index.html");
}
}
```

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/vane/we.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="plugins.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCaF3Xp-29k7VdixW4PzUU4wmtRAM7T-RA&sensor=false"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="loader"><img src="load.png"></div>


<div id="weather">
    <div class="swiper-container swiper-1" id="mainswipe">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide ordinary">
                    <div class="swiper-container swiper-2">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="scroller">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide ordinary" id="places_main">
                    <div class="card">
                    <input type="text" class="search" id="search" onclick="if(this.value=='Enter a place.'){this.value=''; this.select()} else    {this.select()}" value="Enter a place."></input><div class="go" onclick="addPlace()">+</div>
                    <div id="placeholder">
                        <div class="swiper-container places">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="places">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>
<div id="rate">
        <div id="rate_title">Rate Us</div>
        <div id="rate_content">Show us how much you love this app by rating us on the app store. Thank you for checking us out.</div>
        <a href="http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=630139527&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software&mt=8"><div class="button confirm">Rate Us</div></a>
        <div class="button remind" onclick="$('#rate').fadeOut()">Remind me later</div>
        <div class="button never" onclick="never_again()">Never ask me again</div>
  </div>
  <div id='alertbox'>
        <div id='alertheader'>ALERT</div>
        <div id='alertcontent'>
                <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class='close' onclick='cancelalert()'>Close</div>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
  <div class="half">
        <div id="header"><div id="back" onclick="hide_info()">Back</div>About</div>
        <div id="video">
            <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KLbYRPIZ5-4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div id="scroller">
        <div class="setting">
            <div class="label">Unit</div>
            <div id="unit">C</div><div class="degree">&ordm;</div>
            <div class="switch" onclick="changeUnit()"><div id="toggle"></div></div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: got any relevant code?   did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16410297/794088  ?

Comment: Yea I saw that.. no luck! But the app works properly in my phone and some other devices on which i tested on.. **The Problem is Only in some devices it doesn't work..**

Comment: @AmitJoseph add also the html. The relevant part will be with where you specify the addresses of the external resources: css + js

Comment: I'm facing the same issue... has this ever been resolved?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a known bug in the file protocol for a few android versions. If you are referencing files with url parameters a HTTP 404 (file not found) occurs and the file is not loaded.

In your case the "style.css?1" is not loded.

[Overcoming Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich’s Broken WebView URLs](http://fur.dworetzky.name/blog/2012/04/27/overcoming-honeycomb-and-ice-cream-sandwichs-broken-webview-urls-the-quick-n-dirty-way/)

Comment: Link seems to be broken

Comment: Link is broken. Solution is incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

you edite code +

```
super.onStart();

WebView webView =  (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

//enable JavaScript ***
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

if javascript not working, just add this:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What's the additional content compared to ali_m_mkh's answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution was already given by another user, though. Please read [answer] to learn how to add more value with your contributions.